# computer won't boot from us nor boot in safe mode

Tags: boot, virus, safe-mode

The computer of a friend of ours is infected with the Ukash virus, I've created a bootable HitmanPro USB drive to remove the virus but each time I select an option from the hitman boot options the computer just reboots. Even when i try to start in safe mode the computer just reboots again.

Anyone know how to proceed in order to get the hitmanpro usb drive to boot so i can get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can always create bootable usb with any linux OS like [this example](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Then when you boot Linux you can delete all the malicious stuff from you PC

I haven't used HitmanPro, so sorry I can't help with that exact problem.

Comment: Do you know any software for ubuntu that can check for these kinds of rootkits and MBR hijacks?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-mrt/,BitDefender, AVast there are more, not sure which is good and which isn't. Maybe google around that to see experiances  http://bit.ly/171JGUV

Comment: [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) is one of the classic Linux virus scanners.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of Linux based Live-CDs that come with a variety of anti-virus utilities. See this [link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-av-cd.html) for some examples. I haven't personally used any of these, but I've heard from people successfully rescuing their system. I'm sure you can google for specific malware and find a system suited to what you need.